Unknown word (CssSyntaxError) in my html document
I am pretty new to development. I am getting this error and I don't know what's wrong. I think I have all the extensions installed that I will need for the project. I am using vs-code.
I don't know if it is maybe an error that I have in my CSS doc. I don't think I have any there.
Can someone please help me?
I have tried installing new extensions, but it didn't work.


body {
  background-color: #211F2B;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.divider {
  width: 100px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #617BFF;
}

input,
textarea {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #1E1C29;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px #617BFF solid;
}

.container {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

input[name="amount"] {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#submit-btn {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px #617BFF solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: #617BFF;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#submit-btn:hover {
  border: 2px #8095FF solid;
  background-color: #8095FF;
}

#submit-btn:disabled {
  border: 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) solid;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

textarea[name="address"] {
  resize: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 2.7rem;
  font-family: "SFMono-Regular", Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>DBank</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
 
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="dbank_logo.png" alt="DBank logo" width="100"/>
      <h1>Current Balance: $<span id="value">234</span></h1>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <form action="#">
      <h2>Amount to Top Up</h2>
      <input id="input-amount" type="number" step="0.01" min=0 name="topUp" value=""/>
      <h2>Amount to Withdraw</h2>
      <input id="withdrawal-amount" type="number" name="withdraw" step="0.01" min=0 value=""/>
      <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Finalise Transaction" />
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>




The syntax checker in VS Code doesn't always get things right. I have run your CSS and HTML through the online validators and can't find any syntax errors. If you find that your code works fine in the browser, you may need to just ignore what VS Code is telling you.

I do not see any issues in your code, It seems that some extension or VS Code cache issue.
Try to disable all extensions if the problem solves, than enable them one by one to figure out which one is causing the false syntax error. Alternatively you can try to clear cache of your VS Code

Can you show us the exact error, includuing any hint at file or line:column position.

I've edited the question tags. The error you see is shown by a third-party extension in your text editor, seemingly a CSS code style linter that doesn't expect HTML.
